# MySQL Workbench Results

Tags: mysql-workbench

How do disable the Result in workbench?

The reason I am asking is that after certain number of results displayed, MySQL pops up with a message "The maximum result is reached for results. Do you want to continue?" something along those line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't disable results or result sets as these are the meat of any database client tool. A result is what you get when you query your database. Disabling that would mean you don't do anything meaningful anymore with the database.

The error you get, however, is shown because you got **too many** results to display. Each query, which returns a result set, creates a tab in the result area. Creating too many tabs no only makes no sense, since you cannot really see them, but also consumes a lot of system resources. So there's this sanity check in MySQL Workbench to avoid creating too many.

Solution: make sure your scripts/queries don't return more result sets than what you have set in your settings:

[image]

or increase that amount via preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor -> Max number of result sets, but use a sane value there!

Comment: Thank you that makes so much sense now.